# jQuery for each item assign content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the following code to loop through an array of objects and to display the name of each object in html code:

```
var doors = [
    {
        name: "1",
        link: "#1"
    },
    {
        name: "2",
        link: "#2"
    }
];

$('.object').each(function(i) {
      
        this.innerHTML = '<p>' + doors[i].name + '</p>';
     
      });
```

Now, clicking on the div opens a popup containing an iframe (using the class "popup-iframe").

Is there a way to change the link of the iframe corresponding to the selection on click? So if I click on "2", I would like to change the link to the corresponding link.

I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
$('.object').each(function(i) {

var link = doors[i].link;

$(this).click(function(){

    $('.popup-iframe').innerHTML = '<iframe src="'+ link +'" title="Test"></iframe>';

});

});
```

The simplified html code looks as follows:

```
<div id="grid">

<div class="object item-1"></div>
<div class="object item-2"></div>

</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are mixing jQuery and DOM

Answer (score 0):

Use html() function in jquery instead of innerHTML.

innerHTML is a DOM Element property.

JS :

```
const doors = [
    {
        name: "1",
        link: "#1"
    },
    {
        name: "2",
        link: "https://jsfiddle.net/"
    }
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.object').each(function(i) {
        let link = doors[i].link;
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.popup').html('<iframe src="'+ link +'" title="Test"></iframe>');
        });
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="object item-1">item1</div>
    <div class="object item-2">item2</div>
    <div class="popup"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```